# Is Google App Engine sockets support iOS as client?

Tags: java, ios, sockets, google-app-engine

According to the documentation of Google App Engine in this URL https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/
It said:

> Sockets are only available for paid apps, and traffic from sockets is billed as outgoing bandwidth.

My questions is that, Is this paragraph includes iOS Apps too? If Yes, what does that mean?

Comment: Why do you use java and android tags on a question about iOS ?

Comment: I'm using it because Google App Engine server could be written with java and we can use it with iOS and Android in client side.

Comment: Removed the android tag because it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google App Engine is simply a web host. The code you deploy there doesn't run on any devices- it runs in the cloud and clients can talk to it. Whatever you deploy there typically offers up content over HTTP, which any type of client can understand.

That paragraph is talking about billing *for your web application*, that is, the code deployed on your Google App Engine instance.

Thus to serve up content using sockets, you need to have a paid Google App Engine instance. "Apps" does not refer to the client applications.